# Adding Image filters using opengl es

Tags: android, opengl-es

I am looking to make different filters like adding gradients,effects to images. Are there any reference tutorials for this?
Any coding example?

Comment: OpenGL es 2.0 is what i am working with

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps:

http://blog.jayway.com/2010/02/15/opengl-es-tutorial-for-android-%E2%80%93-part-v/

Comment: I am looking for adding 2d effects like how photoshop filters are there.